# Groovy Syntax Confusion

Tags: groovy

I'm new to Groovy/Gradle and I'm currently learning the syntax, but I'm a bit confused by its syntax because it seems that same thing can be achieved by a lot of different ways. Does anyone know what's the meaning of the following groovy code:

```
something(x, y) { 
    // some code here 
}
```

It is definitely not a method declaration because it doesn't have the `def` keyword. It also doesn't look like an invocation of the `something` method, because that wouldn't explain the curly braces. What exactly does this code do?

Answer (score 1):

> It is definitely not a method declaration because it doesn't have the
> def keyword.

Method definitions do not require the `def` keyword.

> It also doesn't look like an invocation of the something method,
> because that wouldn't explain the curly braces. What exactly does this
> code do?

```
something(x, y) { 
    // some code here 
}
```

It is an invocation of a method.  That code is invoking a method named `something` and passing 3 parameters.  `x` and `y` are the first 2 parameters and a `groovy.lang.Closure` is the 3rd.  That code is the same as the following:

```
def closure = {
    // some code here
}
something(x, y, closure)
```

Comment: + the same as `something( x , y, { /*code here*/ } )`

Comment: @chengxing1993xc The comment that dagget left is correct, but is not idiomatic.  It will indeed compile and behave though. The language allows for a closure literal to be expressed outside of parens for readability.  Defining the closure literal inside of the parens is allowed by the language, but discouraged by practice.